# Question on div positioning and responsive design

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, position, responsive

I have been using website builder ‘cargo’ but it’s too limiting for my purpose so I would like to code the site myself. There are two things I want to keep about the cargo design that I don’t know how to do:

1. To have divs resize proportionally like in this screen recording: https://streamable.com/v7cn9 - can this responsive design be done using CSS only?
2. The ability to drag divs freely to set their position in the design (I am creating a ‘randomly’ laid out image gallery) Is there a coding program/tool/website that lets you do drag and drop and also lets you write the code? Not Squarespace, Wix, etc. - Rather than writing out each position manually.

Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, this responsive design can be done with only `CSS` for that you
   can use [`CSS Media Queries`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).
2. You can simply make them draggable without any 3rd party tools. This is an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_draggable) of it taken from `w3schools` website. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you foer the reply. - Sorry, I wasn't clear on point 2. I meant I want it to be draggable while designing the layout - not for the actual live site.